# Automatically delete pods with status 'completed' periodically and across namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm having **Spring Cloud Dataflow** deployed in multiple namespaces of my kubernetes cluster.

Additionally, a task is registered there which is executed from time to time.
Executing a Task in SCDF on kubernetes will create a pod for each execution, and if it's successful, the pod will not be deleted, but set to 'completed' instead.

I am looking for a way to automatically remove those completed pods regularily after a given amount of time (e.g. days). Also, best case scenario would be if that would work across namespaces, but i am not sure if this possible.

Do you know of any way to achieve this?

My first thought was CronJob with `busybox`, but i am not sure if i can give a CronJob the required permissions to delete ressources in a cluster and it would probably require to be deployed in each namespace that i want to delete ressources from.

Let me know of your thoughts, thanks in advance guys

Comment: Is it a `CronJob` which creates the pod?

Comment: check this out, maybe helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64888599/spring-cloud-data-flow-pod-cleanup